# Call to ioctl() on a usb device using usbfs does not work

Tags: linux, qt, usb, driver

I am trying to create my own driver for my Gamepad right now, I found out the original reason why I wanted to create it does not exist but I still want to do it for the experience. **So please don't tell me there is a better way to do this than writing my own driver.**

The part in kernelspace with the *ioctl* function that should be called is:

```
static int xpad_ioctl (struct usb_interface *intf, unsigned int code,void *buf) {
    //struct usb_xpad *xpad = usb_get_intfdata(intf);
    printk(KERN_INFO"(Ongy)IOCTL called\n");

    //if (_IOC_TYPE(code) != XPAD_IOMAGIC) return -ENOTTY;
    //if (_IOC_NR(code) > XPAD_IOMAX) return -ENOTTY;
    switch(code){
        case XPAD_IORMAP:
            printk(KERN_INFO"(Ongy)IORMAP called\n");
            break;
        default:
           return -EINVAL;
    }
    return 0;
}

static struct usb_driver xpad_driver =
{
    .name = "Cyborg-V5-driver",
    .probe = xpad_probe,
    .disconnect = xpad_disconnect,
    .unlocked_ioctl = xpad_ioctl,
    .id_table = xpad_table,
};
```

The part in userspace to call it is (this is part of a Qt-application):

```
int openfile() {
    char *device = "/dev/bus/usb/005/009";
    printf("Opening device %s\n", device);
    return open(device, /*O_RDONLY*/O_WRONLY | O_NONBLOCK );
}
```

[...] the closefile(int file_desc) is missing here, this and the openfile functions exist because of me not knowing one can call "::open()" when Qt overrides function calls.

```
void MainContainer::callioctl() {
    int file_desc, ret_val;
    errno = 0;
    file_desc = openfile();
    if (file_desc==-1){
        printf("Ioctl notcalled because of: error %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }
    else
    {
        errno = 0;
        //struct usbdevfs_getdriver* driver = (usbdevfs_getdriver*)malloc(sizeof(struct usbdevfs_getdriver));
        struct mappingpair* pair = (mappingpair*)malloc(sizeof(struct mappingpair));
        ret_val = ioctl(file_desc, XPAD_IORMAP, pair);
        //printf("Drivername %s\n", driver->driver);
        closefile(file_desc);
        if (ret_val==-1) printf("Ioctl failed with error %s\n", strerror(errno));
        else printf("Ioctl call successfull\n");
    }
}
```

ok, the string to the file I open I get with a call to lsusb and change it by hand in the code, this is only for debugging and until I get the ioctl calls working

When I call the callioctl() it prints:

```
Ioctl failed with error Unpassender IOCTL (I/O-Control) für das Gerät
```

The German part means "wrong ioctl (I/O-Control) for the device" and nothing appears in `dmesg`, that is why I think my ioctl function in the driver is not called.

Comment: Is `xpad_probe` ever called?

Comment: yes I tested wether my driver is used by assigning different input events to the buttons, and see the prints I use to identify my driver in dmesg

Answer (score 0):

If you look at http://www.hep.by/gnu/kernel/usb/usbfs.html it says that to send an `ioctl` to the `usb_driver` device you need to do:

```
struct usbdevfs_ioctl {
    int     ifno;
    int     ioctl_code;
    void    *data;
};

/* user mode call looks like this.
 * 'request' becomes the driver->ioctl() 'code' parameter.
 * the size of 'param' is encoded in 'request', and that data
 * is copied to or from the driver->ioctl() 'buf' parameter.
 */
static int
usbdev_ioctl (int fd, int ifno, unsigned request, void *param)
{
        struct usbdevfs_ioctl   wrapper;

        wrapper.ifno = ifno;
        wrapper.ioctl_code = request;
        wrapper.data = param;

        return ioctl (fd, USBDEVFS_IOCTL, &wrapper);
}
```

The documentation is listing usb device under `/proc/bus` so admittedly this may have changed.